# Dynamic route with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native app running with react navigation 3.9 with 2 components `Signup` and `Event`:

```
export default class Signup extends React.Component {
}


export default class Event extends React.Component {
}
```

Also there is a splash component which retrieve local token.

Whenever there is a token retrieved from local drive, then the initial route is `Event`. Otherwise the it is `Signup`.

```
const stack = createStackNavigator ({
   Event: Event,
   Signup: Signup,
},{
  InitialRouteName: InitRoute  //<<either Event or Signup
})

const initScreen = createSwitchNavigator({
  Splash: Splash,
  App: stack,
})

export default createAppContainer(initScreen)
```

Here `InitRoute` needs to be set by checking local token which is retrieved in splash component. Dynamic routes is not very straight forward with react navigation. What is a good way to implement it with react navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dynamic routes based on the token. You'll need a screen that renders those two routes. Like

```
// app renders createStackNavigator with Event and Signup
const routes = {
  Event: {
    screen: Event,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Event',
    },
  },
  Signup: {
    screen: Signup,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Signup',
    },
  },
};

class App extends React.Component {

  // creates dynamic routes
  createDynamicRoutes = initiaRoute => {
    return createAppContainer(
      createStackNavigator(routes, {
        initialRouteName: initiaRoute,
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    // get initial route from splash screen
    // this.props.navigation.navigate('App', { init: 'init screen' });
    const initiaRoute = this.props.navigation.state.params.init || 'Event';

    // create routes and set initial route
    const AppContainer = this.createDynamicRoutes(initiaRoute);
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

InitScreen navigator renders App and Splash

```
const InitScreen = createSwitchNavigator({
  Splash: Splash,
  App: App,
})

export default createAppContainer(InitScreen);
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/react-navigation-dynamic-routes)

Comment: `Junius L.` many thanks. This is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I am adding a createBottomTabNavigator to the route. const bottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator({Event: EventStack, Signup: SignupStack}). There are multiple screens in both EventStack and SignupStack. Can I use the similar logic as you provided here? I am building a dynamic routing structure that I can  reuse. Thanks.