# Dynamic Routes in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Can it be possible to make dynamic routes in bottom tab navigator of React Navigation.If Possible then how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic route? What functionality do you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392339/dynamic-route-with-react-navigation

Comment: Suppose I have lots of Category.It will be fetch from Api. Now I want to display category in Drawer Navigation or tab navigation.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/limitations.html), it requires you to define routes statically, and there's no officially supported way to define dynamic routes. There are existing workarounds (see the link in my comment under your question), but these workarounds are pretty awkward.

React Navigation 5.0 [was announced recently](https://blog.expo.io/announcing-react-navigation-5-0-bd9e5d45569e), and it promises to bring dynamic configuration support, which might mean dynamic routes as well.