# React Native: How to hide bottom bar before login and show it once the user is logged in?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I want to show the bottom bar after the user is logged in in the app. Currently it is showing when app starts.

Here is my code for bottom bar:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import React from 'react';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HOME: { screen: HomeStack },
    SEARCH: { screen: SearchStack },
    ADDMORE: { screen: AddMoreStack },
    USER: { screen: UserStack },
    ME: { screen: ProfileStack },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'HOME') {
          iconName = require('./Images/tab_home.png');
          iconNameFocused = require('./Images/tab_home_selected.png');
        } else if (routeName === 'SEARCH') {
          iconName = require('./Images/tab_search.png');
          iconNameFocused = require('./Images/tab_search_selected.png');
        } else if (routeName === 'ADDMORE') {
          iconName = require('./Images/tab_add_more.png');
          iconNameFocused = require('./Images/tab_add_more_selected.png');
        } else if (routeName === 'USER') {
          iconName = require('./Images/tab_Users.png');
          iconNameFocused = require('./Images/tab_Users_selected.png');
        } else if (routeName === 'ME') {
          iconName = require('./Images/tab_me.png');
          iconNameFocused = require('./Images/tab_me_selected.png');
        }
        if(focused)
        return ( <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20, tintColor }} source={iconNameFocused} /> );
        else
        return ( <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20, tintColor }} source={iconName} /> );
      },
    }),
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#ca375e',
      inactiveTintColor: '#c7c7c7',
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default App;
```

**How can I hide it in initial pages and show it once the user is logged in?**

Comment: use dynamic routes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392339/dynamic-route-with-react-navigation/56395024#56395024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a guest Navigator first

```
const GuestNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoginScreen,
  SignupScreen,
});
```

after that addSwitchNavigator in createAppContainer

```
const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) =>
  createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        SignedIn: {
          screen: TabNavigator,
        },
        SignedOut: {
          screen: GuestNavigator,
        },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: signedIn ? 'SignedIn' : 'SignedOut',
      },
    ));
return createRootNavigator;
```

for more check [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) documentation

Comment: @AurangzaibRana How do I handle this in App.js? As you can see this line  in my code  `const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);`. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am new to React Native.

Comment: const userStatus = await isUserLogin();  //return true if user login otherwise false
const App=createRootNavigator(userStatus);       
return App;

Comment: use asyncStorage to user login info https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Comment: Need one more help. Suppose I am going from Login page to Home page, then the bottom bar is not coming. What do I need to do to show the bottom bar?

Comment: do not use  navigate. just update the signedIn value with redux or context api or async storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204197/discussion-between-gautam-shrivastav-and-aurangzaib-rana).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using navigation-stack and navigation-tabs. and show the bottom bar after the user is logged in in the app For that I have a solution. then make a structure like this.

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

if you want to display bottom navigation. create a tab screen function like this.

```
    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HOME: { screen: HomeStack },
    SEARCH: { screen: SearchStack },
    ADDMORE: { screen: AddMoreStack },
    USER: { screen: UserStack },
    ME: { screen: ProfileStack },
  },
```

then call in navigation container.

```
       <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={TabNavigator}
              />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Login"
                  component={LoginScreen}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Signup"
                  component={SignupScreen}
                />
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

After re-organizing the navigation structure, now if we navigate to the Login or Signup screens, the tab bar won't be visible over the screen anymore.

ref : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/